# Getting "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401" on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm creating a mobile application on react native.
Here is my axios component

```
import Axios from "axios";
import { apiBaseURL } from "@enums";
const axios = Axios.create({
    baseURL: apiBaseURL,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
});
export default axios;
```

Here is my login api call

```
const controller_name = "auth/";

export const loginInUser = (data) => {
    let result = axios
        .post(`${controller_name}login/`, data)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('res', res?.data);
            return res.data ? res.data : res;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error('error', err);
            return err.request;
        });
    return result;
};
```

The same api is working fine on web app and on postman but on react native it's showing [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401]. Although there is no authorization required for this api.

I've tried most of the solution available online including adding content-type and empty bearer token.

Comment: Share a successful Postman request.